# CoreLocation location permission dialog not displayed when in split screen

Tags: ios, swift, ipados

Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {}
```

When launched, I expect this code to display the location permission dialog. I've added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key into `Info.plist` file already.

This code works correctly when the application runs in full screen. However, when launched in split screen the dialog never appears.

I couldn't find anybody else battling this problem except for this forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/686064 which didn't come to any conclusion.

I thought it may be the OS limitation, but Google seem to have figured it out:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the app able to present `UIAlert` or other dialogs at the same stage?

Comment: Hi @AbhinavMathur, thanks for the question! It didn't in `viewDidLoad`, but it does in `viewDidAppear`. I've tried moving the location request to `viewDidAppear`, which is now reflected in the updated question, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: Oh, I see. You say "split view" but you actually mean iPad Multitasking. Yeah, interesting. I haven't tried this. But I would expect it to work. Keep in mind that you can't make the dialog appear at all if the user has already weighed in. Have you a genuine [mcve]? Your current code is sort of fake. How would you launch _initially_ into split view multitasking mode?

Comment: Hi @matt, that's a minimal reproducible example actually. You can start a safari in split view, then launch the app with that one view controller.

Comment: Yes, I see it, exactly as described at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/686064

Comment: I think you should file a bug with Apple and see if anything develops.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a confirmation from Apple that this is an operating system level bug. There is no known workaround. It has been fixed in iOS 16.0